# How do I associate a list of strings with an 8 character key?

Tags: c#, wpf, json, string, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` and a `TextBox` on a WPF form. My code behind is in C#. The `ComboBox` contains strings that correspond to the type of email address the user is entering into the `TextBox`.

I want the strings to correspond to 8 character keys that will be serialized into Json with the user entered email address as the value.

The only thing I can think of is something like

```
if this.ComboBox.SelectedItem == "Some String"
JsonObject thingToSerialize = new JsonObject(){key = 'smestrng', value = TextBox.Text}
```

I really want to bind a `List<string>` to the `ComboBox` items and have those strings associated with the 8 character keys. Something where I could write a few lines that searches the list, finds the string, and then gets the corresponding 8 character key.

I hope I'm not over-complicating this. I could hack something together using a bunch of if statements, but I am sure I will hate myself in 8 months when I realize I have to scale this up and rewrite it completely. I'm not sure if there are going to be three or four keys or 75 keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing WPF, it's *always* best to structure your data correctly. By that, I mean that if you want to have an e-mail address linked with a key of some sort, then create a simple class that has two properties; `EmailAddress` and `Key`. Of course, you might also want to add more properties, such as `Name`, etc.

Then you can data bind a collection of these class instances to your `ComboBox.ItemsSource` property and set the [`DisplayMemberPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to display the `EmailAddress` property value, while still containing the other values too. Finally, add a property of the type of your class named `SelectedItem` and data bind this to the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` property:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}" DisplayMemberPath="EmailAddress" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
JsonObject thingToSerialize = new JsonObject() { key = SelectedItem.Key, value = 
    SelectedItem.EmailAddress };
```